# Is there an Azure B2C sample app hosted anywhere?

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, sample, hosted-app

There used to be a hosted sample app at https://woodgrovegroceriesb2c.azurewebsites.net/, but the sample app/website is no longer there. It was nice to be able to see what Azure B2C does out of the box. Is there a hosted sample app anywhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

https://woodgrovegroceriesb2cdemo.azurewebsites.net/

The old site seems to have been taken down.